# List results in groups

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble 'sorting' my mysql results in php.

Here's the database I have

```
id¦ value  ¦ category
---------------------------
1 ¦ Value1 ¦ category1
2 ¦ Value2 ¦ category2
3 ¦ Value3 ¦ category2
4 ¦ Value4 ¦ category3
5 ¦ Value5 ¦ category1
6 ¦ Value6 ¦ category1
```

What I'm trying to do, is to get a result in php looking like this:

category1

- Value1
- Value5
- Value6

category2

- Value2
- Value3

category3

- Value4

Any help is useful. Thanks

Comment: I would prefer to create tables Categories and Values, where Value.category_id defines its connection to Categories table, then you can simply fetch the result grouped by Category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone for the help. I'm going to use a mix of AlienWebguy's and jchavannes's code which is working perfect, just what i was searching for.

the code looks like this:

**SQL:**

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$results = mysql_query($SQL);
```

**PHP:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $myArray[$row['category']][] = $row['value'];   
}

foreach($myArray as $key => $val)
{
    echo $key;
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($val as $v)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $v . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: since you are using their code, I think its fair to give them a vote up for that at least :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM theTable SORT BY category ASC';
```

PHP:

```
$results = mysql_fetch....($SQL);
$record_table = array();

// Create the array for the list
foreach($results as $row)
{
   $record_table[$row['category']][] = $row['value'];
}

// Output the HTML list
foreach($record_table as $key => $val)
{
    echo '<ul id="' . $key . '">';

    foreach($val as $v)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $v . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, you will simply overwrite category with new values instead of adding them.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, value, category FROM table;
```

Then in PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myArray[$row['category']][] = $row['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the result-set, create array key within your initial array for each new category you encounter and push value data into it.

If key for category exists, skip the key creation stage and just add the data.

Then you can loop through generated array and output all the data (array of values) per category (key).

Answer (score 0):

use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and you will get the output will be in string separated by `,`

```
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) AS valueList FROM tableName GROUP BY category
```

You can also use some format of GROUP_CONCAT(). Like

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( value SEPARATOR ‘-’ )
```

above query will use `-` instead of `,`

To change the order and shorting

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( value ORDER BY Category DESC )
```

and then re arrange by ur scripting language, if using php then try with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

**Note:** `GROUP_CONCAT()` ignores NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution done with just one loop.

```
$currentCategory = null;
$closeTag = "";

//Using MySQLi since mysql_* functions are obsoletes
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

/**
 * Here I use an ORDER BY to group the result by categories
 */
$selectStmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, value, category FROM table_name ORDER BY category ASC");
$selectStmt->execute();        
$selectStmt->bind_result($id, $value, $category);
while($selectStmt->fetch()) {
    if ($currentCategory != $category) {
        /**
         * In the first iteration this variable will be empty, so the <ul> tag 
         * will not be closed
         */
        echo $closeTag; //Close the last category list
        echo $category;
        echo '<ul>';            
        $closeTag = '</ul>';
        $currentCategory = $category;
    }
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```